# Image Upload with Multiple Sizes

Tags: flash, file-upload, plupload

I'm looking for a javascript/Flash solution that will help in shortening large file upload times from a user's perspective.

When the user selects multiple images, I'd like to immediately upload a small version of all the images to the server (I need to run some server side code on it then display it back to the user). Once the small images are uploaded, I want to then upload larger versions of the images, which are stored on our server for later use.

Is anyone aware of something that would support this in IE8+? I'm currently trying to modify plupload, but it's not working so well (I've got the html5 system almost there but I have no clue how I'm going to deal with Flash). Ideally I'd like one solution that supports both HTML5 and Flash, but one that only supports Flash is ok as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [THIS FLASH](http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/06/07/client-side-image-resize-flash-cs4-filereferencedata/) that does that.